# Firebase from Spark to Blaze

Tags: firebase

[picture problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgIPI.png)

Note: my credit card work fine in google pay .

how can i contact the support ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a problem like this previously, most times you may have that same card linked to several google services in which one of them has a pending bill to pay.

OR

There have been errors when a google service has tried charging this card and it failed.

OR

You have an outstanding payment (which is very unlikely to cause an error)

**What I did when I had this problem**

> ***"I USED ANOTHER CARD"***

Comment: thank you for your attention

Comment: In this google account I only use Firebase, I added this credit card to google pay and no problem
Can I contact the support team to find out the problem?

Comment: @AbdelmalekBourhim , This should take you to a page where you can complain on this  particular matter
https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/billing/upgrade/verify

Comment: I sent an email..hope they help me..thanks for your valuable time my friend

Comment: I have another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70461580/how-can-i-contact-google-cloud-billing-support-from-this-web-page